# How can I replicate edit-mode "Subdivide" in a non-destructive way?

Tags: geometry-nodes, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

The First Shape is using a catmull-clark smooth modifier, and the second shape is using the subdivide option in edit mode.

[image: using subdivision surface modifier] [image: using subdivide with smoothness in edit mode]

I want to know if there's a way (maybe using geo nodes?) to subdivide an object the same way as in edit mode, where the original vertices don't move - but as a non-destructive modifier.

Does anybody know if the edit mode subdivide math/algorithm/method has a specific name? it might help search for a way to replicate it with nodes, or find someone who already has.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is the setup.
Capture attribute captures the original position of each vertex. You mix that with the position of the current of the subdivided mesh using a mix node set to vector influencing the position socket in the set position node and hey presto you get the factor of the mix node controlling the amount of smoothing.

I don't know if the movement is going to be 100% as you want it, but it is 100% reversable and 100% keyframeable.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Believe it or not I'd thought of something like this a while ago, but it's not exactly what I had in mind as the vertices still move from their original positions too much.
Unfortunately it was best thing I could come up with using my current geo nodes knowledge, as I couldn't quite figure out how to displace and reshape the mesh based off of edge angle or vertex density, not that that would work anyway.